# How to access data of other user?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

I am working on a Symfony 2.7 webapp that uses the FOSUserBundle. Everything works fine so far. Not I would like to add an Admin Backend, that allow to show details about different Users.

For example in a Phone Book App, on should be able to see how many contacts a selected user has created:

```
$contact_count = $this->contactsCountForUser(5);
...

public function contactsCountForUser($user_id) {
    $repo = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Contact');

    $qb = $repo->createQueryBuilder('c');
    $qb->select('COUNT(c)');
    $qb->where('c.user = :userId');
    $qb->setParameter('userId', $user_id);           

    $sql = $qb->getQuery()->getSql();
    $count = $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();

    return $count;
}
```

This fails, since the following is created as SQL query:

```
SELECT COUNT(c0_.guid) AS sclr0 FROM contact c0_ WHERE (c0_.user_id = ?) AND (c0_.user_id = '1')
```

**Problem 1:**
Why is `$qb->where('c.user = :userId')` being translated to `c0_.user_id = ?`? Why isn't 5 beeing used as user_id?

**Problem 2:**
`AND (c0_.user_id = '1')` is automatically added to the query. I assume this is done by the FOSUserBundle which limits the query to the current user. Here ID 1 is the ID of the currently logged in user, which is the Admin... Obviously `(c0_.user_id = ?) AND (c0_.user_id = '1')` can never be true.

**So: How do I convince Doctrine and/or the FOSUserBundle, that the admin should be able to execute queries on other users data?**

Comment: are you sure that parameter `$user_id` is valid ? try to dump his value and let me know...

Comment: Yes I am. Even when I remove the variable and use a hard coded value like `qb->setParameter('userId', 5)` or `qb->setParameter('userId', '5')` (with 5 in quotes), I get the same result

Comment: You query seems to be correct and i can't see anything wrong with it ... now try to add this code inside your function `print 'method executed : public function contactsCountForUser($user_id)';` maybe **contactsCountForUser** is redefined somewhere else ....

Comment: I already did this: I simply added `$count = $sql` at the end to return the created SQL Statement instead of the count value (which was always 0). The result was, that the query was included in the output of the page, instead of the count value. Thus I know for sure, that this method is called and nothing else. You can see the created query in the question.

Comment: Do you have any class extending from SQLFilter? We're working as well with Symfony 2.7 and FOSUser but there is no additional WHERE condition on the current user. But we implemented an additional WHERE condition on some tenant_id (custom table field) by adding a custom SQLFilter - in that case every (!) SQL query sent to DB is automatically adding the WHERE tenant_id = someParam.

Comment: @LBA Thank you very much for that hint! This was indeed causing this problem. A piece of third-party code added an SQLFilter as `UserAware` annotation. Quite obvious if you know what you are doing :-P I will add an answer to describe that in more detail. Maybe it can save others from not seeing the problem :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of @LBA, I was able to find the source of the problem:

A piece of third-party code add an SQLFilter as `UserAware` annotation. [This webpage](http://www.michaelperrin.fr/2014/07/25/doctrine-filters/) describes in detail what is done and how it works.

Maybe this can help others to avoid this kind of "problem" and to figure out what is "wrong" :-)

About Problem 1: Even after solving Problem 2, Problem 1 is still the same. The userId is still translated to `?` within the query. However this does not seem to influence the function of the code. As far as I can see everything is working as expected.

Comment: If I right understand what you're saying i think that ? is because you're using (with doctrine) prepared statement.

Comment: @Mattia is correct - it's just because you're using the prepared statement here - the 'real' SQL will have the ? replaced by your parameters.